# AT commands to connect Firebase using modem a9g

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sim800

I`d like to know how can I send data from modem gsm connected! to esp32 with at commands?
I use this at command to send to thingspeak

```
String cmdString = "AT+HTTPGET="``http://api.thingspeak.com/update.json?api_key=``" + apiKey +"&field1=" + temperatura + "&field2=" + humitat +"&field3=0.0&field4=0.0" + """;
```

but I can't get with firebase.
Thanks in advance!

Connecting firebase with at commands httpget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be referring to the Firebase Realtime Database, in which case all it's APIs are described in the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database). It doesn't have an API that accepts [AT commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_AT_command_set), but the closest equivalent is its [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start).

Comment: Thanks Frank, I'll take a look at it. All this is new for me.

Comment: Hi Frank, I found this "at command" but for sim808 to connect direct with firebase. **"AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\","+FIREBASE_HOST+".json?auth="+FIREBASE_SECRET**
Only that attach a **"name":"-Nmv77LZ3A0Y8bSKhVl9"** that changes  on every data inserted. I'm looking for rest api but with my level of coding I will spend a lot of time. Thanks again

Comment: The `-Nmv77LZ3A0Y8bSKhVl9` looks like a so-called push key from Firebase, which it generates when you send a `POST` request. If you don't want to generate such a push key, you can send a `PUT` request. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-ways-to-save

Comment: Thanks. @Frank, sim808 has not PUT request. I will try with other options, rest api.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with sim808 sending to php and Firebase Admin PHP SDK.  Thanks.
I need to ask about at commands for a9g because TinyGPS sometimes work sometimes not and I do'nt know how to get response **"at+location=2"**
and separate as lat and lng. Thanks

Comment: I think it's solved by getting the response as a string to, later, separate it with index and substring.

Comment: At the moment, not solved.